# Ignore elements during marshalling without using @XmlTransient

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to ignore certain elements without using @XmlTransient when marshalling

> ```
> JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
>
>         Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
>         marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
> ```

The reason for without is because other developers using the xml bean might want to marshal those elements.

Comment: Why without? You should clarify what your requirements are.

Comment: The reason for without is because other developers using the xml bean might want to marshal those elements.

Comment: I would say, but take this as my opinion, that if every dev choose what's serialized or not, you're looking at a big mess. So don't do that..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude some fields from XML, you can set value of it to `null`.
`null` fields are not marshalled to XML
**Example:**
DTO:

```
class Customer
{
   private String a;
   // getters/setter
}
```

Logic:

```
Customer customerInstance = ...; // some business logic with Customer instance
//... business logic
customerInstance.setA(null);     // set null before marshalling
// marshalling
```

property `a` will be absent in XML

Comment: `Customer customerInstance = new Customer();customerInstance.setA(null);` sounds like a NOP to me

Answer (score 0):

Well guys,

I think the simple answer is to create another class of "Customer" model without those fields

```
class CustomerA{

@XmlElement
private String name;

//@XmlElement   // Element that I do not want to keep
//Private Date dob;

}
```

All I need to do is set the values into CustomerA and since java pass by value references for objects, I only incur a bit of reference byte.

I believe this is the cheapest and most simple way and I have control over that domain.